# Are there any perl script for to check the newly added vobs and modules in base clearcase

Tags: perl, clearcase

***Are there any perl scripts to check the newly added vobs and modules in base clearcase?***

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

The usual technique is to set triggers which can do any action you want (including sending a notification email for instance):

- as mentioned in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=42495), you cannot set a trigger on mkvob (creation of a new vob)
- you could create a trigger ([`cleartool mktrtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm)) on `mkcomp` (creation of a new component)

so the only other solution is some kind of polling daemon which would at regular interval do a

```
cleartool lsvob
# for each UCM vob
cleartool lscomp -invob \anUCMVob
```